# Asking links of MSE questions and references

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am still new in MSE,and still learning how to use MSE properly. Sorry in advance.

MSE has really nice Elementary number theory questions and so many nice elementary diophantine equation , and since I am learning Number theory , I want to solve more questions , specifically diophantine equations, but searching them is hard on MSE , cause there a lot!!

So will it be appropriate to post a question on MSE , asking for "nice and beautiful diophantine  questions and links one has solved and would recommend a Olympiad number theory student to try " or something like that ? I mean there a lot of experts on MSE , who will be very happy to share their favourite questions.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question (whether it is allowed to ask for such thing on the main site). But since you seem to be interested in finding interesting questions in some specific tag (or specific area), I will pint out that you could try to use the data available about various questions to find the ones which are more popular. I have collected approaches I was able to think of here in chat: [How to find interesting questions in a specific tag?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/how-to-find-interesting-questions-in-a-specific-tag)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: that's really a lot of important and useful info in your chat. A boon for newcomers so to speak. +1 and thanks a ton for your comment.

Comment: The main site is for asking math questions. So you should not ask for links to other questions there. You can use the tags of your interest and search within tag for questions.

Comment: Also one can view the questions bookmarked (earlier this was known as favorites) by a specific user but then this is something not to be encouraged as the focus here is not on specific users but on useful content.